# QDataStream reads and writes more bytes than QFile::length() reports to have

Tags: c++, qt, qdatastream

I have a utility that should copy files from one location to another.

The problem I have is when reading X bytes using the [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) and writing it, the number of bytes being read/written exceeds the number of bytes the file has. I see this problem happen with a number of files.

I am using a [QDataStream::readRawData()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#readRawData) and [QDataStream::writeRawData()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#readRawData) to facilitate reading/writing to and from files as shown below

```
 QDataStream in(&sourceFile);
 QDataStream out(&newFile);

 // Read/Write byte containers
 qint64 fileBytesRead = 0;
 quint64 fileBytesWritten = 0;
 qint64 bytesWrittenNow = 0;

 quint8* buffer = new quint8[bufSize];
 while ((fileBytesRead = in.readRawData((char*)buffer, bufSize)) != 0) {

      // Check if we have a read/write mismatch
      if (fileBytesRead == -1) {
           printCritical(TAG, QString("Mismatch read/write: [R:%1/W:%2], total file write/max [W:%3/M:%4]. File may be corrupted, skipping...").arg(QString::number(fileBytesRead), QString::number(bytesWrittenNow), QString::number(fileBytesWritten), QString::number(storageFile.size)));

           // close source file handle
           sourceFile.close();

           // Close file handle
           newFile.close();

           return BackupResult::IOError;
      }

      // Write buffer to file stream
      bytesWrittenNow = out.writeRawData((const char*)buffer, fileBytesRead);

      // Check if we have a read/write mismatch
      if (bytesWrittenNow == -1) {
           printCritical(TAG, QString("Mismatch read/write: [R:%1/W:%2], total file write/max [W:%3/M:%4]. File may be corrupted, skipping...").arg(QString::number(fileBytesRead), QString::number(bytesWrittenNow), QString::number(fileBytesWritten), QString::number(storageFile.size)));

           // close source file handle
           sourceFile.close();

           // Close file handle
           newFile.close();

           return BackupResult::IOError;
      }

      // Add current buffer size to written bytes
      fileBytesWritten += bytesWrittenNow;

      if(fileBytesWritten > storageFile.size) {
          qWarning() << "Extra bytes read/written exceeding file length";    <================= this line is hit every now and then
      }

      //...
```

This problem isn't consistent, but it happens every now and then, I have no idea why. Anyone have thoughts on a possible cause?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but... why not just use [`QFile::copy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy-1) or even [`std::filesystem::copy_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) if you can make use of `c++17`?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the function [QDataStream::writeRawData()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#writeRawData) sounds like ideal for writing binary data. Unfortunately, that's only half of the story.

The open-mode of the file is relevant as well under certain conditions – e.g. if the `QFile` is opened on *Windows* with [QIODevice::Text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum):

> QIODevice::Text
>
> When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.

I prepared an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate that:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtCore>

void write(const QString &fileName, const char *data, size_t size, QIODevice::OpenMode mode)
{
  qDebug() << "Open file" << fileName;
  QFile qFile(fileName);
  qFile.open(mode | QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  QDataStream out(&qFile);
  const int ret = out.writeRawData(data, size);
  qDebug() << ret << "bytes written.";
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char data[] = {
    '\x00', '\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x05', '\x06', '\x07',
    '\x08', '\x09', '\x0a', '\x0b', '\x0c', '\x0d', '\x0e', '\x0f'
  };
  const size_t size = sizeof data / sizeof *data;
  write("data.txt", data, size, 0);
  write("test.txt", data, size, QIODevice::Text);
}
```

Built and tested in VS2017 on Windows 10:

```
Open file "data.txt"
16 bytes written.
Open file "test.txt"
16 bytes written.
```

Result inspected with the help of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ ls -l *.txt
-rwxrwx---+ 1 scheff DomÃ¤nen-Benutzer 427 Jun 23 08:24 CMakeLists.txt
-rwxrwx---+ 1 scheff DomÃ¤nen-Benutzer  16 Jun 23 08:37 data.txt
-rwxrwx---+ 1 scheff DomÃ¤nen-Benutzer  17 Jun 23 08:37 test.txt

$
```

`data.txt` has 16 bytes as expected but `test.txt` has 17 bytes. Oops!

```
$ hexdump -C data.txt
00000000  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  |................|
00000010

$ hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0d 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e  |................|
00000010  0f                                                |.|
00000011

$
```

Obviously, the underlying Windows file function “corrected” the `\n` to `\r\n` – `09 0a 0b` became `09 0d 0a 0b`. Hence, there occurs one additional byte which was not part of the originally written data.

Similar effects may happen when the `QFile` is opened for reading with `QIODevice::Text` involved.